# openpyxl reading google monthly budget template sheet

Tags: python, google-sheets, openpyxl

I copied a monthly budget report that I made using the google monthly budget sheet template and when I try to make a workbook object using openpyxl and attempt to verify the object by using the type() function, python returns a nonetype error. Does anyone know if openpyxl can read google sheets made from the google monthly budget sheet template? (the following code only tests to see if openpyxl can read a google sheet using the monthly budget template if you downloaded it locally. if you want to modify using the google drive api, here is the url: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oUGwLLZT_4Yuc65N-N7i4WjlBZZSAz9Av9Ni4IpflCY/edit?usp=sharing) if you need anything else, please ask

Here is an example of code:

```py
def write_to_expense_report():
    
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("C:\\Users\\mander8317\\Documents\\Programming\\convert-bank-statement-to-expense-report\\jan-test-budget.xlsx")

    print("test returning the sheetnames of the google sheet")
    print(wb.sheetnames)
```

Comment: Please post the code you are using to create the workbook. See [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also you could use the Drive API to export the file into .xlsx which can likely be used to instantiate a workbook with openpyxl

Answer (score 0):

Google sheets has it's own API ([docs for Python](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python)). You'll need to read the data from the sheet using Google's API and then use openpyxl to create a new workbook and input the data.